# 1 + 1/2 * 1/3 + (1 * 3)/(2 * 4) * 1/5 + (1 * 3 * 5)/(2 * 4 * 6) * 1/7 + .. converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

To prove that $1+ \frac{1}{2} 
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}  \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{7}+.... 
 $ converges.

If i attempt to find the nth term for this series i fail

I tired to make the denominator a factorial so that the series become like

$$1+ \frac{1}{3!} 
+\frac{3.3}{5!} +\frac{3.3.5.5}{7!}  +\frac{3.3.5.5.7.7}{9!}+ .... 
 $$
What would be the numerator of the nth term of this series

$$a_n = \frac{?}{(2n+1)!}, n=0,1,2,...$$

How does this series converges?

This is an exercise probelm 8 in methods of real analysis by Richard R goldberg, please help me with the proof.